# How to select rows with only Numeric Characters in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to keep rows only with Numeric Character i.e. 0-9. My source data can have any type of character e.g. 2,%,( .

```
Input (postcode)
3453gds sdg3
454232
sdg(*d^
452

Expected Output (postcode)
454232
452
```

I have tried using `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(postcode, '^[[:digit:]]+$');`
however in my version of Oracle I get an error saying

> function regexp_like(character varying, "unknown") does not exist

Comment: That error message doesn't sound like Oracle - that sounds more like Postgres.

Comment: why not clean the data before it is loaded into the system (or better yet, add input guards so users can't enter incorrect data)? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For `Oracle 10` or higher you can use `regexp` functions. In earlier versions translate function will help you :

```
SELECT  postcode
FROM    table_name
WHERE   length(translate(postcode,'0123456789','1')) is null
AND     postcode IS NOT NULL;
```

OR

```
SELECT translate(postcode, '0123456789' || translate(postcode,'x123456789','x'),'0123456789') nums
   FROM table_name  ;
```

the above answer also works for me

```
SELECT translate('1234bsdfs3@23##PU', '0123456789' || translate('1234bsdfs3@23##PU','x123456789','x'),'0123456789') nums
   FROM dual  ;

Nums:
1234323
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this and get nulls in my postcode column for every row so its not working as it should. I would like to keep rows that contain only numeric number 0-9

Comment: I tried this and can still see postcodes with letters like GB2 2G6

Comment: @Andrew Shouldn't this be the other way around, i.e. compare with `is null` to get the rows to keep, and `is not null` for getting the rows to delete?

Comment: @bp123 now see my last two updated answer and let me know which works

Comment: @Adder yes i already did it but bp123 says its not working for him which is very strange

Comment: @Andrew you are mixing replacement with empty string and with `1` in your solution 2 and 3. I think it should be empty string in solution 3, too. And Quotes are missing on solution 2.

Comment: @Adder let bp123 try it thats why i have added extra condition in where clause...if it doesnt work then what you said its correct

Comment: @bp123 the last answer should definately work as i have tested it

Answer (score 0):

You want `regexp_like()` and your version should work:

```
select t.*
from t
where regexp_like(t.postcode, '^[0-9]+$');
```

However, your error looks more like a Postgres error, so perhaps this will work:

```
t.postcode ~ '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and get the same error function regexp_like(character varying, "unknown") does not exist

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative to the Gordon Linoff answer, we can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(postcode, '[0-9]+', '') IS NULL;
```

The idea here is to strip away all digit characters, and then assert that nothing were left behind.  For a mixed digit-letter value, the regex replacement would result in a non-empty string.

Comment: `= ''` will never be true in Oracle as there is no separate 'empty string'.

Comment: @Bill Yes you're right, I should be doing a null check.